# bpchar convertion to date during import

Tags: postgresql, greenplum

I would like to convert bpchar to date during import from the other database.
To create an external table it should be matched with the parameters of the table in the other database.
Finally, I need the simple table with the column with date type, not bpchar

For example:

1. table to be imported

```
CREATE TABLE example (
    mouse bpchar(4),
    "date" bpchar(10),
    quantity int4
);
```

2. external table should be like the first one
3. the final table should be

```
CREATE TABLE example (
    mouse bpchar(4),
    "date" date,
    quantity int4
);
```

date format 31.01.2021

i tried simple conversion to date ::date

but it was an error in the create statement

Comment: I don't have a problem creating either table. You will need to provide detailed information about the problem you are having, starting with providing the entire error message as text update to your question text.

Answer (score 1):

Providing all contents of the field `"date"` has valid dates, you can create a new table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE newexample AS 
SELECT mouse, to_date("date",'DD.MM.YYYY'), quantity FROM example;
```

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/VGW3wktg)

Comment: i need to create an external table not example one
structure and data types of the columns should be similar to the first table

Comment: When you want to create an "external table", why are you **asking** about: "bpchar convertion to date" ? The seems to be something different..

Comment: What exactly do you mean by external table? 1: An OS file? In which case there is likely no data type specifications, just strings either delimited or fixed fields. 2: A table is another RDBMS. If  so which  database. 3: A non-relational database. Again if so which.

Comment: The answer covers the essence. Use `to_date()` in a view you define on the "external table".